# How replace hibernate OrderImpl on hibernate 6? (Spring Boot 3 migration)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, java-17

`org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.OrderImpl` does not exist anymore on `hibernate` `6.1.7-final` (version used on Spring Boot `3.0.5`) is there a way to replace it other than implement one myself?

Tried to replace with a custom implementation but I'm stuck on this

```java
error: "(...).OrderImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmSortSpecification"
```

**Update:**
Still need to validate completely, but for now I've replace:

```java
new OrderImpl(expression, isAcending);
```

for:

```java
isAscending ? criteriabuilder.asc(expression) : criteriabuilder.desc(expression);
```

It seems to be working as expected now.

Comment: Please provide more details of your use case. Ordering can be implemented by just using methods generated with JPA repository interbace.

Comment: We have sorting and ordering creation in runtime, depending on the API request. We use criteria builder and specification (depending on the entity being search) and we add the OrderImpl instance (with the order by expression) to properly create the query.

Comment: Still need to validate completely, but for now I've replace:
new OrderImpl(expression, isAcending);
for
isAscending ? criteriabuilder.asc(expression) : criteriabuilder.desc(expression);

Comment: It has been a while. Could you confirm your final solution? It would also be greatly appreciated if you could post it as an answer to your own question and select it as the solution.

Comment: just did, it does work with no problems for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my specific use CriteriaBuilder::asc(~) and CriteriaBuilder::desc(~) does work.

```
new OrderImpl(expression, isAcending);
```

for:

```
isAscending ? criteriabuilder.asc(expression) : criteriabuilder.desc(expression);
```